# How to change devise's sign out to use POST instead of GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I noticed that the sign out action of devise uses GET (I think the best practice is to put all data state-changing actions behind a POST)

So how do I change the route to use a POST instead of a GET ? (Ideally without having to copy the controller code if at all that is needed)

Here's the `rake route` for the current devise sign out path (wrapped on two lines):

```
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)
         {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
Latest devise version (v1.2.rc-10) has an option called `:sign_out_via` ([link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L72))